# How to split the right hand side of the equation because it is crossing the page

Tags: line-spacing

The equation that I want to split is

```
$$\frac{\partial (r^2 A_{t, r})}{\partial r}+(\alpha^2 r^2-
\frac{4M}{\alpha r})^{-1} \frac{\partial A_{t, \phi}}{\partial \phi}=
-2q\delta(r-\frac{(4M)^{\frac{1}{3}} a}{\alpha})\delta(\cos\phi - 1)$$
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You could do something like `\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial (r^2 A_{t, r})}{\partial r}+(\alpha^2 r^2-
\frac{4M}{\alpha r})^{-1} \frac{\partial A_{t, \phi}}{\partial \phi}=\\
-2q\delta(r-\frac{(4M)^{\frac{1}{3}} a}{\alpha})\delta(\cos\phi - 1)
\end{align*}` using the `amsmath` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could load the `amsmath` package and employ a `multline*` environment.

[image]

Note that I've increased the sizes of two pairs of round pairs viw `\biggl(` and `\biggr)`.

Do also note that one shouldn't use `$$` to initiate and terminate display-math mode in a LaTeX document. For more on this topic, please see the posting [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % use a narrow column width
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'multline*' environment
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
\frac{\partial (r^2 A_{t, r})}{\partial r}
+\biggl(\alpha^2 r^2-\frac{4M}{\alpha r}\biggr)^{\!-1}\, 
\frac{\partial A_{t, \phi}}{\partial \phi}\\
=-2q\delta\biggl(r-\frac{(4M)^{1/3} a}{\alpha}\biggr)
\delta(\cos\phi - 1)
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

with `multlined` from the package `mathtools` and shortness `\pdv{...}{...}` for partial derivative from the package `physics`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{multlined}[0.6\linewidth]
\pdv{(r^2 A_{t, r})}{r} + 
    \left(\alpha^2 r^2 - \frac{4M}{\alpha r}\right)^{-1} 
    \pdv{A_{t, \phi}}{\phi}   \\
= -2q\delta\left(r-\frac{(4M)^{1/3} a}{\alpha}\right)\delta(\cos\phi - 1)
\end{multlined}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]